# JsonSerializable: call standard serialization from serialize method

Tags: java, json, serialization, fasterxml

The problem is in `serialize` method (*see code section of my question*). All looks well till my `ComplexGraph` class swell to twenty ot thirty fields. When `ComplexGraph` become a real complex graph, than it's very ugly to serialize each field via `jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", id)`.

***Question:*** How can I invoke standard serialization in `serialize` method? Like:

```
public class ComplexGraph implements JsonSerializable {
    public void serialize(JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (isPrivate) return;
        //HERE IS THE QUESTION
        else jsonGenerator.standardSerialization(this);
    }
}
```

***Code:***

```
public class ComplexGraph implements JsonSerializable {

    private int id;
    private String text;
    private boolean isPrivate;

    // getters and setters

    @Override
    public void serialize(JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (isPrivate) return;
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        //IT'S VERY UGLY WHEN complexGraph HAS MANY DEPENDENCIES!
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", id);
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("text", text);
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider, TypeSerializer typeSerializer) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        serialize(jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);
    }
}
```